# L298N 50 Hz noise

Tags: l298

I am currently measuring a 50 Hz noise with an oscilloscope on a L298N with no load and a 1 mOhm resistor, which I can't explain. I have connected the L298N to an Arduino and a 12V power supply. The square wave signal from the Arduino and the 12V power supply have no measurable 50Hz noise. I measure between the two outputs of the L298N. The 50 Hz noise on the L298N only occurs when both inputs are at 0V input voltage. If one input is at 3.3V, no noise occurs. When I measure between the ground of the L298N and an output, no noise occurs. Does anyone know what this could be and how I could fix this problem?

[image: 50Hz noise, measured by the oszilloscope]

Comment: Please show the exact schematic and post it into your question. Please also link the pdf data sheet of the device you are using.

Comment: Also, what you are using for an oscilloscope.

Comment: This question can be voted for reopening once you add the details needed to be sure what you’re asking about. I made some educated guesses, but that’s not the standard a good question should aspire to.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you’re shorting the power supply’s grounded secondary via the oscilloscope to ground. To make measurements with a single probe, the Arduino and the driver have to be floating with relation to mains earth. The power supply used must have high impedance between its output and the ground clip of the scope probe (measure that!). Nothing else mains-supplied can be connected to the system - especially not a PC that has its 0V connected to earth.

Likeliest connection to ground from your circuit is via the USB line to the Arduino. In that case, those peaks are due to short circuit current flowing through: the PC’s motherboard, USB cable, Arduino board, scope probe cable, scope's internals, and the mains cords of both scope and the laptop.

To make such measurements without worrying about all that, use two scope channels- one for each output - and subtract them with math mode.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I made the measurement also without a connection to the PC but have the same effect.

Comment: Later, the two electrodes will be suspended directly in a liquid. Grounding is not possible there, so I would like to do without grounding already during the measurement in order to have a setup that is as realistic as possible.